# trying to parse String into Date and time as Date(data type) in java

Tags: java, date, parsing, datetime-format

```java
String input = "2022-04-05 21:11:06";
```

required output:

```java
Date output = 2022-04-05 21:11:06;
```

My code

```java
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date var4 = df.parse(input);
```

but I got error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-04-05 21:11:06"
```

Comment: How are you going to do proper parsing if your format starts from day but your input starts from year?

Comment: Note that a `Date` doesn't have a format. It's just an instant in time. See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2017/04/23/all-about-java-util-date/

Comment: Your input and output are the same.  Do you mean to parse the current DateTime into that format?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't use the old `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes.  Instead, use `LocalDateTime`, `ZonedDateTime`, and `DateTimeFormatter`

```
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse(
    "2022-04-05 21:11:06",
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
);
```

Comment: Or use string manipulation: `LocalDateTime.parse( "2022-04-05 21:11:06".replace( " " , "T" ) )`

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying wrong SimpleDateFormat. change  this

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

to  `SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");`

Comment: As usual, please note that `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are deprecated.

Comment: tried this one as well ...its giving wrong output: Mon Oct 13 21:11:06 IST 10

Answer (score 1):

As Alexey R mentioned your pattern need some correction:

```
String input = "2022-04-05 21:11:06";
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date v = df.parse(input);
System.out.println(v);
```

Comment: As usual, please note that `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are deprecated.

Comment: yeah, that's true, thank you for your comment.

Comment: @mantrs, if its working & suits your requirement, please accept answer for benefit of SO communitiy.